# zxJDBC postgresのCOPYコマンドについて

Tags: python

JythonでzxJDBCを使用し、postgresのデータベースに接続しています。
DELETEコマンドはエラー無くDB上のデータを消すことができたのですが、COPYコマンドを実行すると以下のエラーが出てしまいます・・・よろしくお願いいたします。

```
[error] zxJDBC.Error ( Cannot create PyString with non-byte value )
```

```py
import sys
load("C:postgresql-42.1.3.jre6.jar")
from com.ziclix.python.sql import zxJDBC
url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"
dbuser = "postgres"
dbpassword = "postgres"
driver =  "org.postgresql.Driver"
dbconn=zxJDBC.connect(url, dbuser, dbpassword, driver)
dbcur = dbconn.cursor()

#dbcur.execute("delete from test") 
#dbcur.execute("copy test from 'C:test.csv'")
dbconn.commit()
dbcur.close()
dbconn.close()
```